# How access Vue Js computed properties?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the next code with vuejs, i call axios method post and set the authenticated user correctly(cosole show the user), but when i call the computed property in the component the user is empty

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isAuth: null,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        authenticatedUser () {
            return this.getAuthenticatedUser()
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.isAuth = this.$auth.isAuthenticated()
        this.setAuthenticatedUser()
    },
    methods: {
        setAuthenticatedUser () {
            axios.get('/api/user')
                .then(response => {
                    this.$auth.setAuthenticatedUser(response.data)
                    console.log(this.$auth.getAuthenticatedUser())
            })
        },
        getAuthenticatedUser(){
            return this.$auth.getAuthenticatedUser()
        }
    },
    router
}
```

And this my code for get the authenticated user

```
export default function (Vue) {
let authenticatedUser = {};

Vue.auth = {
    //set token
    setToken (token, expiration) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', token)
        localStorage.setItem('expiration', expiration)
    },
    //get token
    getToken() {
        var token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        var expiration = localStorage.getItem('expiration')

        if( !token || !expiration)
            return null
        if(Date.now() > parseInt(expiration)){
            this.destroyToken()
            return null
        }
        else{
            return token
        }
    },
    //destroy token
    destroyToken() {
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
        localStorage.removeItem('expiration')
    },
    //isAuthenticated
    isAuthenticated() {
        if(this.getToken())
            return true
        else
            return false
    },

    setAuthenticatedUser(data){
        return authenticatedUser = data;
    },

    getAuthenticatedUser(){
        return authenticatedUser;
    },
}

Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    $auth: {
        get() {
            return Vue.auth
        }
    }
})
}
```

When i not use the computed property
[image: When i not use the computed property]

When i use the computed property in the model
[image: When i use the computed property in the model]

Comment: Rather than setting global `Vue` properties, I highly recommend a state-management system like vuex

Answer (score 0):

Your computed property won't be updated because this.$auth is out of the instance’s scope (i.e. not reactive).

I would use vuex, putting the user inside the global state:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    user (state, user) {
      state.user = user
    }
  }
})
```

and then watch changes in your component:

```js
import store from 'path/to/store'

store.watch(state => {
  return state.user
}, () => {
  // process authenticated user
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `$auth` another Vue instance and install it as a plugin, this way, it will be accessible from any other Vue instance.

```
function Auth(Vue) {
    let auth = new Vue({    
        data: {
            // your auth data
            authenticatedUser = {}, // This one is now reactive
        },    
        computed: {
            // your auth computed properties
        },    
        methods: {
            // your auth methods
            setAuthenticatedUser(data){
                return this.authenticatedUser = data
            },
        }    
    })
    Vue.prototype.$auth = auth
}
```

To use this plugin, simply call:

```
Vue.use(Auth)
```

Now, you can access the authenticated user from any Vue component like this:

```
this.$auth.authenticatedUser
```